# Add gradient to MaterialShapeDrawable

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I make this view using MaterialShapeDrawable and it looks good, but I need to make it gradient.
Does anyone face it?
It will be another shape in production, but I need to achieve this drawable with gradient

[image]